# Using EChartOption to type the options of an Angular 16 NgxECharts Area Chart?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, echarts, ngx-echarts

Trying to type the options as `EChartsOption` instead of any in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-rkcqq2?file=src%2Fecharts.component.ts) demo.

And if the switch is made like this:

```
  options!: EChartsOption;
  //options!: any;
```

Then the linting creates this error:

```
Type '{ normal: { color: string; }; emphasis: { color: string; borderColor: string; borderWidth: number; }; }' is not assignable to type 'ItemStyleOption<CallbackDataParams>'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'normal' does not exist in type 'ItemStyleOption<CallbackDataParams>'.
```

And I'm trying to figure out whether the chart configuration is wrong or the `EChartsOption` type is not complete.

When the type is set to `any`, the chart renders fine, and it does support the `normal` declaration as defined:

```
normal: {
       color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)',
},
```

Looking at the [ECharts documentation](https://echarts.apache.org/v4/en/option.html#series) I don't see `itemStyle` listed under `series`.

However it does work ...

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`itemStyle` is listed under `series:{type: 'line', ...}`, [[docs link](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-line.itemStyle)]. (Not very relevant, but I see  you linked to echarts docs for v4 but your stackblitz is using the latest v5.)

However, `itemStyle` doesn't have neither a `normal` nor an `emphasis` subcategory. The emphasis itemStyle is under `emphasis.itemStyle` [[docs link](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-line.emphasis.itemStyle)]

So, the itemStyle options should be structured like this:

```js
{
   series: [{
      type: 'line',
      // ... other options
      itemStyle:{
         color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)', // for "normal"
       },
       emphasis:{
          itemStyle:{
              color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
              borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
              borderWidth: 2,
          }
       }
    }]
}
```